# I uninstalled Unity by mistake

Tags: unity, software-installation

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I uninstalled Unity from the Software Center by mistake. How do I reinstall it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute the following commands :
To open the terminal on desktop press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Or ... perform the commands from a virtual console.
To access the virtual console press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter user name and password and then execute the commands.
After the installation is finished - I recommend to restart the PC.

```
sudo reboot
```

**Update - addressing your follow up LXDE question :**
When the login screen appears select Unity and log in.
If you want to **uninstall the LXDE desktop** - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge lxde
```

Comment: desktop appears but how do i acess the terminal

Comment: does not work what should i do

Comment: what do you mean by a virtual console.

Comment: @ShahjalalAlam : Press Ctrl + Alt + F1 ... the whole screen is a terminal now ... :)

Comment: after hard work I got lxde to work but not unity so now i can access the terminal but not unity so how can i uninstall lxde and get unity

Comment: `ubuntu-desktop` depends on `unity` so third command is redundant..

Comment: I did it but I still boot into lxde.

Comment: @ShahjalalAlam : Please repeat the complete prodedure - reinstall Unity from within the LXDE desktop environment - after a reboot choose Untiy session from login screen - uninstall LXDE - after reboot you should be able to boot into Unity desktop ! :)

Comment: It finally worked but when I switch users there is a still option for switching to lxde.